# Annotating useNavigation type when it is used in a generic component

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

TLDR:
**Is it possible to annotate the useNavigation hook in a generic component?**

If I create a `<BackButton />` component that uses the `useNavigation()` hook is there a way to have it correctly type the hook when it is used in multiple screens?

The [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript#annotating-usenavigation) recommend typing this as:

```
const navigation = useNavigation<XScreenNavigationProp>();
```

However, this only works for when using `useNavigation` in a specific screen. How does one annotate the hook for more than one screen?

Answer (score 3):

You should specify a default type:

```
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#specifying-default-types-for-usenavigation-link-ref-etc

Specifying a default type means you don't need to annotate it. This is perfect for generic components which are used in multiple places.

Comment: That's useful, thanks. It will still however be missing part of the type definition depending on navigation nesting and where the component is used but I imagine it would not be possible to fully type a generic component.